# How do I resolve this Error: ENOENT: no such file or file or directory, open '/tmp/mt-1miyjxv/os.json' at error native?

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor, enoent

I recently upgraded to meteor 1.4.1.1 from an older version. But now I cant seem to start my app anymore!

Help!

After upgrading, I get into the directory of my app then run "meteor --port 7123" which used to (work) fire-up my app in the previous meteor version, but cant seem to get past this error message:

[image: This is a screenshot of the error message that I get while trying to start my app]

After running meteor --port 7123 I get: 
    Downloading meteor-tool@1.1.10... this process never completes, then comes the error message indicated in the attached message.

A little research shows that the ENOENT in the error means Error NO ENTity. and I might have a problem with the file, or maybe my path or name of file is wrong. How do I correct this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Additional information: after running meteor --port 7123 I get:

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Adding "54.192.225.217 warehouse.meteor.com" to my host file fixed the issue.

If your environment is Ubuntu, then open the terminal and paste

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/hosts
```

Paste: "54.192.225.217 warehouse.meteor.com" at the end of the file. save and close. Now run your app.

Comment: Thanks. Helped me.

Comment: The original author should mark this answer as Answered.

Comment: Worked. Any reason for it not to work without this fix? Is the file broken on the blocked IP?

Comment: Thanks @SirBT, it helped me

Comment: Worked for me on mac too.  What is the root cause of this?

Comment: Why this is a solution?

Comment: sudo echo "54.192.225.217 warehouse.meteor.com" >> /etc/hosts # will append that line to /etc/hosts ! Thanks for the solution, it works for me. This was a funny one!

Comment: Thanks, worked for me on mac as well. How did you find out this solution? Who are you?

Comment: @vantesllar You are welcome. Mmm... I cant remember how I worked out the solution, as it was quite a while back. All I remember was that the error after the meteor upgrade was eating into my deadline so I did extensive research on how to downgrade the meteor version, I think that was how I stumbled on the solution. Also check this out: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7303 What specifically would you like to know about me?

Comment: @WojciechBednarski am not too sure why this a working solution but you could read abit more about it here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7303

Comment: @JaredMartin am not too sure why this a working solution but you might find this link useful: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7303

Comment: @AbhishekBiswal Not too sure, but the meteor guys seem to be working on fixing this. You might find this link useful: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7303

Comment: @SirBT just kidding, wondering how can a human know something like that.

Comment: @vantesllar lol Thanks, It was nothing really I was just in a desperate position ding to fix my app...

Comment: For those less experienced with CLI, this also works fine using nano, etc. in place of gedit.