# How do I find out what packages I had installed in my previouse meteor app?

Tags: javascript, meteor, package, atmosphere

I recently upgraded to the latest version of meteor. The currently installed meteor version is Meteor 1.4.1.

In trying to ***continue*** developing my app (from the previous version) in the upgraded meteor environment, I figured I would create a new app (meteor create newApp) then copy (the code from the original app) and paste (the code into the newly created files) then run it.

I quickly released that I have to re-install the packages that my original app was depending on or else I get error messages.

The issue here is I don't remember the packages my original app is dependent on. I still have the original app folder, which I created in the previous meteor version. Is there a way to extract the list of packages from the original app? 
Alternatively is there a way I can merely **continue** developing and running the original app without having to create a new app and copy and pasting the code? If so how do I do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the app root go to `./meteor` directory. In that folder open `packages` files. All your installed packages names will be there.

Alternatively, you can use `meteor list` command in the app directory.

Answer to the second part, yes you can continue developing the same app. The packages will be upgraded accordingly. You may face some issues with `bcrypt` if you are using accounts-passwords package but there are workaround to get over that.

Comment: Thank you Ankit, I was able to find/see the list of packages at the ./meteor. However when I try to continue developing the same app, I get this error message on start-up: /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_1.1l5666a++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:165
      throw error;
      ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/mt-1hjvegg/os.json'
    at Error (native).                                                                                                 Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: This may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153477/how-do-i-resolve-this-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-file-or-directory-open-t

Comment: Oh! That is actually your answer! So I assume that your issue was resolved.