# Meteor 1.4.1.1 thrown error when add angular templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, web

I just install Meteor 1.4.1.1. on my 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04. But I haven't luck when trying to add angular templates. 
Here is the error message I've got:

/home/wandyatmono/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_1.1l5666a++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/isopackets/ddp/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:165
      throw error;
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/mt-14c7sa8/os.json'
    at Error (native)

Can somebody tell me why?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this command:

`meteor npm rebuild`

If the issue is still un-resolved- Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153477/how-do-i-resolve-this-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-file-or-directory-open-t)

To Quote the solution there:

> Adding "54.192.225.217 warehouse.meteor.com" to my host file fixed the issue.
>
> If your environment is Ubuntu, then open the terminal and paste

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/hosts Paste: "54.192.225.217 warehouse.meteor.com"
```

> at the end of the file. save and close. Now run your app.

Comment: Thank you Ankit. Solved.

Comment: Welcome. This usually happens where there are issues with versions of npm packages' dependencies. Rebuilding it solves the issue.

Comment: Such a genius! Thx so much!

Comment: No i've still same problem even on `meteor npm rebuild`
`/home/yash/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_1.139xb76++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/isopackets/ddp/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:165
      throw error;
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/mt-1hnp4wc/plugin.compileNGTemplate.os/program.json'
    at Error (native)`

Comment: @Yash  try this solution- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153477/how-do-i-resolve-this-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-file-or-directory-open-t