# Patch update to Meteor 1.4.1.2 fail to find program.json

Tags: meteor, osx-elcapitan

The command to update Meteor `meteor update --patch` gave the error:

> $meteor update --patch
>   /Users/empl1/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_2.5y3whq++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/ddp/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:165
>         throw error;
>         ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/private/var/folders/8y/63l591316sz2mxwr1kq551bm0000gp/T/mt-hqj7n0/plugin.compileLessBatch.os/program.json'
    at Error (native)

Any idea what can fix this? Thanks

Comment: Hi Fred.  This might have been already been answered.  Please see this "hack" to fix it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153477/how-do-i-resolve-this-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-file-or-directory-open-t/39174861#39174861and let me know if it worked for you.