# Error creating an angular based meteor application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I am following the docs of meteor [here](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/templates) for creating an angular app.
These are the commands I used:

```
meteor create simple-todos
meteor npm install
meteor // tested it, was working fine
meteor remove blaze-html-templates
meteor add angular-templates
```

On the last command, I get this error:

```
/home/cortana/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_2.354htk++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/isopackets/ddp/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:165
      throw error;
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/mt-92ybvz/os.json'
    at Error (native)
```

What is the problem here?

Meteor version I am using is `v1.4.1.2`

Comment: did you mean meteor add angular-templates (using a hypen instead of a space?)

Comment: See this SO question for that specific error message. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153477/how-do-i-resolve-this-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-file-or-directory-open-t